# POM function not sending keys

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, pageobjects

I defined a function in my page object that which would fill out fields in a form when called in my spec file.  However when I run my test spec, nothing happens.  Can anyone take a look at my code and give me some insight on what's wrong?

spec.js

```
var aboutYou = require('../page_objects/aboutYou.js')


describe('Credit Application', function() {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        browser.get('http://localhost:5000'); 
    });

    describe('before form submission', function() {

        it('should fill out the name fields', function() {
            // Nothing Happens
            aboutYou.fillFields;

            // This sendKeys to the email field
            aboutYou.emailAddress.sendKeys("example@ramen.com");
        });

    });
});
```

aboutYou.js

```
var AboutYou = function() {

    this.firstName = browser.findElement(by.css(".section-aboutyou:not(.joint) input[formControlName=firstName]"));
    this.lastName = element(by.css(".section-aboutyou:not(.joint) input[formControlName=lastName]"));
    this.dateOfBirth = element(by.css(".section-aboutyou:not(.joint) input[formControlName=dateOfBirth]"));
    this.homePhone = element(by.css(".section-aboutyou:not(.joint) input[formControlName=homePhone]"));
    this.emailAddress = element(by.css(".section-aboutyou:not(.joint) input[formControlName=emailAddress]"));

    this.fillFields = function() {
        firstName.sendKeys("Randy");
        lastName.sendKeys("Dinh");
    };
};

module.exports = new AboutYou();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

aboutYou.fillFields(); should do the trick my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke fillFields like that:

```
aboutYou.fillFields();
```

Comment: Oh right.  Because it's a function.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks so much.